# Cronjob every 24 minutes

Tags: cron

I want very specific a cronjob every 24 minutes.

By doing:

```
*/24 * * * * /usr/bin/php /test.php
```

Would this cron run every 0, 24, 48, 12, 36, 0 minutes or just 0, 24, 48?

If it only runs on 0, 24, 48 minutes, what would be the good one to run a cronjob every 0, 24, 48, 12, 36, 0 minutes?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is off-topic. There are plenty of other questions about crontabs on Stack Overflow that haven't been closed -- and crontab arguably is a (very special-purpose) programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would run at 0, 24, and 48 minutes after the hour.

Since 24 minutes is exactly 1/5 of 2 hours, you can use two entries to run a job every 24 minutes:

```
*/24     */2    * * * /usr/bin/php /test.php
12-36/24 1-23/2 * * * /usr/bin/php /test.php
```

or perhaps more simply:

```
0,24,48 */2    * * * /usr/bin/php /test.php
12,36   1-23/2 * * * /usr/bin/php /test.php
```

(Incidentally, putting your `test.php` script in the root directory is an odd choice.)

Comment: The test.php was an example haha. Thanks for solving my problem!